# Webpack 4 doesn't create CSS file without babel-preset-es2015

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, webpack-4

I'm having an odd issue since upgrading to Webpack 4 and babel-preset-env. When I remove `es2015` as a preset it doesn't separate the css. Everything else compiles as normal, but no css file unless I include that preset.

My .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "targets": "> 5%, last 2 versions",
        "forceAllTransforms": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true, "decoratorsLegacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true}],
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": [
          "./src"
        ]
      }
    ]
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "react-hot-loader/babel"
      ]
    },
    "production": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-imports"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', path.resolve(__dirname,'./src/index.js')],
  output: {
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash:4].bundle.js',
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash:4].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: './index.html'
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist/']),
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[contenthash:4].css'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/')],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: { minimize: false }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sass|scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: ['./node_modules'],
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        uglifyOptions: {
          keep_fnames: true,
          keep_classnames: true,
          compress: {
            dead_code: true,
            drop_console: true
          },
          mangle: {
            keep_fnames: true
          }
        },
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: true
      }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ],
    runtimeChunk: false,
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        styles: {
          name: 'styles',
          test: /\.css$/,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true
        },
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/].*js/,
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 2
        }
      },
      chunks: 'all'
    }
  }
};
```

I could leave it alone, but including `es2015` is preventing proper chunks from being created as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in this case was removing `"sideEffects": false` from my package.json. Also, changing to `"sideEffects": ["*.scss", "*.css", "*.sass"]` resolved the issue and had an effect on the final build. My understanding is that importing CSS in Webpack can be considered a "side effect" if you're not using CSS modules.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by installing up to date deps which for Babel has moved under a new namespace with `npm i @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react babel-loader@latest` and `npm un babel-core babel-preset-env babel-preset-react`, also updating `.babelrc` to reflect the changes with `"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", ...]` etc.

Then what you really really need to do, is amalgamate your two `plugins` properties into one... right now your config is:

```
config = {
  ...
  plugins: [],
  ...
  plugins: [],
  ...
}
```

The second set of plugins potentially overwrites `MiniCssExtractPlugin`

Comment: I've updated the webpack config I shared here. In my actual code the production config is merged with a common config. A few days ago I updated to babel 7 and had the same result. I can see my scss file going through mini-css-extract but a file is never created.

Comment: Can you update your babelrc file too? I've just run your config on a project of mine and it worked fine.

Comment: Oh right... also the common config could be breaking it too no?

Comment: I've updated my babelrc to show latest babel version. The original babelrc works, but only with es2015 included. Any variation of it without es2015 is what doesn't generate a css file.

Comment: Yeah I still output css with the updated .babelrc & webpack conf file. As mentioned, it could be an issue with the common config you're using. Otherwise there's not really enough info to go off here. You'd have to show more of your project.

Comment: So following your comments here, I made a simple app with the same babelrc and it built correctly. And from that the only difference I found was the "sideEffects" setting was in one package.json and not the other. Removing that line fixed the css issue. Thanks, this really helped work through the problem!

Comment: Hey @RipTheJacker - removing the sideEffects line worked for me after reading your comment. If you add that as an answer, I'll upvote.